# Confirming domain on SparkPost

Tags: laravel, sparkpost

I am using SparkPost to handle all my email. I already have verified the domain and everything but recently I transferred my domain to another hosting site do I need to verify the domain there?Thanks in advance

Comment: if your domain status shows verified and ready for sending, you don't need to verify ownership. but you will want to keep the DNS settings to achieve better deliverability.

Comment: @HungryCoder  Oh okay thanks then I will just leave it the way it is